# When using the xquery function "functx:between-inclusive", is it possible for the first argument to come from 2 different attribute values?

Tags: svg, xquery, functx

I am using xquery to search and compare values from a source xml file against an svg file.
Here is my xquery:

```
for $xval in $figure/graphic/sheet/doc(@svgsrc)//*[text() = $rdi/text()],   
    $line in $figure/graphic/sheet/doc(@svgsrc)/svg/line   
where functx:between-inclusive($xval/@x, $line/@x2, $line/@x1) 
return $line/@class
```

The above xquery works well when all $xval (svg text element) have the @x attribute. However, some $xval have the @transform="matrix(0 -1 1 0 248.402 118.972)" wherein the x value is the 5th position of the matrix.

Is it possible for the first argument of functx:between-inclusive to come from 2 different attribute values?

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it sounds like you want to always select the `@transform` value when `@x` isn't available:

```
for $xval in $figure/graphic/sheet/doc(@svgsrc)//*[text() = $rdi/text()],   
    $line in $figure/graphic/sheet/doc(@svgsrc)/svg/line   
let $x := ($xval/@x, xs:double(tokenize($xval/@transform, '\s')[5]))[1]
where functx:between-inclusive($x, $line/@x2, $line/@x1) 
return $line/@class
```

This will assign to variable `$x` a sequence of both values, selecting only the first one. If the first value is empty, the second is selected because it will be the first value in a 1-item sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Your summation is exactly what i am trying to do. However, adding the let clause still returns nothing. Is there another way? I am using Saxon-EE xquery 9.5.1.7

Comment: This answer does what you asked in the question. If it still doesn't work, then you probably have another error in your code, but it's impossible to know since you haven't provided test data. Also, you reference a variable `$rdi` that's not included in your query, so I assume this is a smaller part of a larger query, further complicating the problem. I suggest you create a smaller test case of the new problem and post it as a separate question with sample data. Accept this answer if it helped you.

Comment: i found the error in the svg file. After i removed these namespaces xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" from the svg file the code works!